# Oxygen isotope analysis

Tags: asteroids

Where can I get a oxygen isotope analysis $^{18}O$ / $^{16}O$ vs $^{17}O$ / $^{16}O$ done commercially ? I witnessed a meteorite fall near me; it looks to be martian andesite. My first number $SiO_2$ 59.32 and my others bring up mars first.

Comment: As I answered in a similar question https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/33651/23748, it is unlikely to be a meteorite and extremely unlikely to be a Martian meteorite.

Comment: I presume that the numbers in first line were intended to be oxygen isotopes and the formula in the last line is intended to be silicon dioxide.

Comment: What do you mean "I witnessed a meteorite fall near me"? On average there are only about 6 [meteorite falls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meteorite_fall) per year worldwide, so it would be quite amazing if you witnessed one, and *unbelievably* good luck if you were the one to locate the crater and retrieve the meteorite itself.

Comment: What is *My first number SiO2 59.32 and my others bring up mars first.*?

Comment: Sio2 59.32 first number on my chemical analysis .when I Google this number that is no where close to retard korotev martian meteorote charts .it brings up mars .59.31 doesn't 59.33 doesn't.most all my numbers bring up mars

Comment: My chemical analysis numbers sio2 59.32 al203 16.62 fe203(t) 9.61 mno .117 mgo 3.04 tio2 0.968 k20 5.78 p203 .14 when I Google these numbers like si02 59