Is there a company that can authenticate Martian meteorites?
I witnessed a meteorite fall. I have had some test done. I believe it is a Martian meteorite. It seems very hard to get any help and was looking for a company who authenticates Martian meteorites for a fee.

different but related: How do scientists know that a rock found on Earth came from Mars? and somewhat less related Is it possible to find what crater the Mars meteorites come from? and Could martian meteorites come from Olympus Mons?

Also see: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/50308/how-can-i-identify-if-my-stone-is-meteorite/50314#50314

You have created multiple accounts.  Please do not create multiple accounts.

Also https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/33770/oxygen-isotope-analysis?noredirect=1&lq=1 You do not have a Meteorite.  You may have a piece of basalt from a hydrothermal vent.

@JamesK thanks for finding the previous post. I knew there was a similar looking post from the same OP. // To OP - as mentioned already, please don't create multiple accounts, you already have 2 accounts. Kindly follow the link mentioned in previous post on account merge.

Also see https://xkcd.com/1723/

An easy way to determine whether a rock is a possible meteorite and worth a look by a scientist is to walk through the Self-test checklist:

Debora Rios and colleagues at the Nacional/UFRJ in Brazil, adapted by Randy L. Korotev, WashU
Also take a look at Meteorwrongs.
If the rock passes the self-test, and you remain convinced that the rock is a meteorite, you will find pointers to institutions that study such rocks at one of the pages linked at the above site.

Thanks @doubleunary.  Note that this person has been walked through this checklist and has gone as far as getting his rock identified as "rock from hydrothermal vent". He posts about once a year to ask the same question.

Perhaps someone can clarify: I'd had the impression that some of the earliest "magnetic stones" found 2,000 years ago were of meteoritic origin... So I'm confused in the self-test checklist that "attracts magnets" is immediately disqualifying.

@paulgarrett I don't see how "attracts magnets" is disqualifying, the paths 1-2-4-5-7 or 1-2-3-8-7 both lead to "Send me some photos".

@GuntramBlohm, oop, thanks, I guess I misread the flow chart. Thanks!

... maybe failing to parse the flow-chart is disqualifying. :)
